# Xamarin OnPageFinished --- getting cookies

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I am overriding this method for my WebView. And I am using the proper domain. When debugging using an Android simulator I only see a partial list of all of the cookies. The one in particular I'm requiring the value of isn't listed. Any suggestions? Source code below.

```html
 public override void OnPageFinished(WebView view, string url)
            {
                base.OnPageFinished(view, url);
                _cookieManager.Flush();                
                string customerId = null;
                var cookies = _cookieManager.GetCookie(Constants.DCH_DOMAIN);
                Log.Info(TAG, string.Format("Cookies retrieved as {0}.", cookies));
                if (cookies != null)
                {
                    string[] tempList = cookies.Split(';');
                    foreach (var pair in tempList)
                    {
                        if (pair.Contains("wishlist_customer_id"))
                        {
                            string[] tempPair = pair.Split('=');
                            customerId = tempPair[1];
                            if (customerId != null)
                            {
                                Log.Info(TAG, string.Format("Customer ID retrieved as {0}.", customerId));
                                PCLStorage(customerId);
                            }                            
                        }
                    }
                }
```

**UPDATE** There is another domain that stores cookies as part of this web session. No different in path, HTML, same site, secure, etc. between the four cookies. I'll attach what Chrome on my workstation looks like, showing these four cookies. Then I'll attach what my Android simulator's device log looks like, where I output the cookie collection based on the subclassed WebViewClient. Only two of the four cookies appear to be there. I inserted a SystemClock.Sleep(5000) before retrieving the cookies, in order to give them a chance to fully populate as well.

[Chrome session](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5Qwi.png)

[WebViewClient session](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVfxD.png)

Comment: Do you mean the cookie is not synchronized to the WebView?

Comment: Well, I see some of the cookies that appear in a typical page pull. But not all of them. I though the Flush() method would force all cookies to be written/stored locally, right?

Comment: Flush() method synchronizes the cookie immediately,the “removeSessionCookies” are called before the synchronization cookie,it is an asynchronous method, so the synchronization process may cause some data to be purged(That's my opinion).Try getting the cookie directly without this line of code

Comment: I tried inspecting the cookie collection with either Flush() commented out or left in. Same result. The collection has most of the cookies, but not all of them that I'd expect. If I pull the same web page on my workstation I can inspect the cookies in Chrome and see all of them. In particular the one that is important to me :) I've ensured the domain I'm pulling cookies for is correct, just strange how not all of the cookies are present in the WebView.

Comment: I am subclassing a WebViewClient, and overriding a few of the parent class' methods. Could this somehow affect CookieManager's behavior? If I could figure out how to inspect all of the CookieManager's elements then perhaps that might shed some light on things...

Comment: If the data is complete when you view the cookie in Chrome, I think you can consider whether you made some mistake when setting the cookie,maybe you could post the code that sets the cookie

Comment: The thing is I didn't set any cookies. They are automatically defined by the website that's being pulled up. I installed Chrome Dev on my Android virtual device and can see all of the cookies present when I pull the page. It's just the WebView that either doesn't properly store them, or else is storing them in a different spot that what one would expect.

Comment: Actually the same outcome using a CustomTab as the WebView. Some of the cookies appear in the CookieManager pull but not all of them. Debugging the AVD from my workstation shows all the cookies when I chrome://inspect remotely but the app itself doesn’t display all of the keys and their corresponding values?

Comment: Apparently the CustomTab doesn't utilize the same cookie store as the WebView does. The former uses the Chrome shared cookie jar. And I cannot find a way to pull its cookie values. So I am sticking with the WebView. Unfortunately I still cannot see all cookies that the website is setting. I set a timer for 10 seconds after page load to then pull the cookies. No luck?

Comment: try using `var cookies = _cookieManager.GetCookie(url)` directly .

Comment: Good idea! I tried that and still only see maybe 50-75% of the total cookies that should be present. I can tell that the client has to be presenting some of these stored cookies, since the page is a web account view. And the user is already seen as being authenticated and "logged in." The web request passes along these cookie values based on what I see in network captures. The one particular cookie value is all I'm looking for :(

Comment: One place I can finally find this cookie is if I manually query /data/data/com.android.browser/app_webview/Cookies with SQLite3. When I have my app run as a CustomTab then the cookie is created and stored here. But I cannot determine how to get to it within my app's code. If I try to open this DB I am getting an error that it cannot be opened. Security reason perhaps?

Comment: I didn't find a good way to open this db in code .I was wondering if should do cookied synchronization before `webview.loadurl`, you try calling `_cookieManager.flush () ` before `loadurl`;

Comment: Good call. That's all it was. I just had to Flush() before loading the URL. That simple. Thanks so much for walking through the scenario. I'll definitely remember this for the next time I need it!

Comment: Glad it helped. Could I post an answer and give me a mark ? Thank you.

Comment: Sure. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should do cookied synchronization before load url to ensure complete cookie data like :

```
_cookieManager.flush ();
webView.loadUrl(url);
```

then get cookies int the OnPageFinished method :

```
public override void OnPageFinished(WebView view, string url)
        {
            base.OnPageFinished(view, url);         
            string customerId = null;
            var cookies = _cookieManager.GetCookie(url);
            Log.Info(TAG, string.Format("Cookies retrieved as {0}.", cookies));
            if (cookies != null)
            {
                string[] tempList = cookies.Split(';');
                foreach (var pair in tempList)
                {
                    if (pair.Contains("wishlist_customer_id"))
                    {
                        string[] tempPair = pair.Split('=');
                        customerId = tempPair[1];
                        if (customerId != null)
                        {
                            Log.Info(TAG, string.Format("Customer ID retrieved as {0}.", customerId));
                            PCLStorage(customerId);
                        }                            
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Leo Zhu the issue has been resolved. Apparently ***before*** I load the WebView URL I needed to flush the CookieManager instance. This resulted in all of the cookies for this particular resource to appear and be available for querying. Hope that this might help anyone else who runs into a similar challenge!